# Objective C, math functions: round a Float32 with two or three decimals

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math, rounding

I'm developing an iPhone app.

I want to round a Float32 number like this 3.124 to this 3.12. Or a number like 4.2258 to 4.226.

How can I do that?

I want to hold this value on a Float32 variable or on a float variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
float x = 4.2258;
x = x * 100;
roundf(x);
x = x / 100;
```

That's one option. You can also use [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Which way do you want to round?

```
x = 0.01 * floorf(0.5 + 100.0 * x);
```